# Increment boost::variant value

Tags: c++, boost, c++98, boost-variant

I have a variant variable where the different types all implement `operator++`. I would like to apply incrementation directly on the variant variable. Is there an easy way to do that ? Or have I to apply it in a switch on each type ?

Simple **example** with stl iterators :

```
typedef boost::variant<
  std::vector<double>::iterator,
  std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator,
  std::set<double>::iterator,
  std::set<double>::reverse_iterator
> AnyIterator;

void incr(AnyIterator& ai)
{
  ++adi; // this doesn't compile: no match for operator++ blah blah blah

  // Have I really to write this kind of ugly thing ?
  if(ai.type() == typeid(std::vector<double>::iterator))
    ++boost::get<std::vector<double>::iterator>(ai);
  else if(ai.type() == typeid(std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator))
    ++boost::get<std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator>(ai);
  else if(ai.type() == typeid(std::set<double>::iterator))
    ++boost::get<std::set<double>::iterator>(ai);
  else if(ai.type() == typeid(std::set<double>::reverse_iterator))
    ++boost::get<std::set<double>::reverse_iterator>(ai);
}
```

**Note :** I use gcc 4.8.1 and Boost 1.57. I don't want solution from C++11, I can't use it due to compatibility with old gcc versions.

Comment: I don't think you can get away from writing this ugly code, but if you need it often you could implement the `++` operator for your `AnyIterator` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a generic functor and then use [`boost::apply_visitor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html) with that functor:

```
namespace detail {
struct incrementer {
    template< typename T >
    void operator()(T& x) const { ++x; }
    typedef void result_type;
};
}

void incr(AnyIterator& ai)
{
  boost::apply_visitor(detail::incrementer(),ai);
}
```

Comment: I see the idea. It looks simple. Can you try to compile your solution ? I have a compilation error about template deduction, with several propositions in notes (too long for a comment). Moreover, why put the structure in the namespace `detail` ? Is it just un good practice ? For which reason ?

Comment: @Caduchon [I see no error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/c9rNAtcSLpS2GrcB). namespace `detail` is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: F**king God ! I missed the `typedef void return_type;`. The error is really impossible to understand ! Thanks, it's working now.

Comment: It seems the better way is inheritance from `boost::static_visitor<>`. But the idea is there.